# Как установить две версии среды Python 32/64?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Windows 10, сейчас установлен Python 3.8 64bit. Возможно ли установить рядом 32bit среду, чтобы можно было переключаться между средами или одновременно запускать нужную? Например, чтобы в рамках одного cmd-скрипта можно было обращаться и к 32-битному интерпретатору, и 64-битному.

В PATH добавлено "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38".

Comment: Конечно. Устанавливаете в 2 разные директории нужные версии и вызывайте необходимый `python.exe` оттуда

Comment: @dIm0n а есть возможность обращаться к утилитам типа pip без полного адреса интерпретатора? Грубо говоря "python pip install" и "python32 pip install"

Comment: На линуксе точно можно, доступны у меня сейчас `python3.8`, `python3`, `python2.7` и так далее. На винде думаю, что тоже можно, но проверить в данный момент не могу. Вроде бы при установке надо галку поставить, которая добавит нужные вещи в PATH

Comment: Хотя, то, что я привёл, относится именно к последовательным версиям питона, а не разрядности. В любом случае можно сделать ярлыки с любыми удобными названиями и добавить их в PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В рамках задачи наиболее удобным оказался вариант с вызовом через py

```
py -3.8-32
py -3.8-64 
py -3.8-32 -m pip install
py -3.8-64 -m pip install
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [pyenv-win](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win).

Позволяет устанавливать несколько версий питона (как 32 так и 64 битных) параллельно и независимо и потом между ними переключаться и использовать.

Comment: Не обязательно использовать именно pyenv-win, есть реализация виртуальных окружений, поставляющаяся вместе с python (начиная с версии 3.3): https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: виртуальные окружения это немного другое. Они не позволяют сами по себе использовать разные версии, например одновременно установить питон 3.5, 3.6 и 3.8

Comment: Интересно, буду знать что такое есть.